# parallelizing loop for GLM in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, glm, parallel-foreach

I am trying to program a parallelized for loop where inside I am trying to optimally find the best GLM to model only the variables that have the lowest p-value to see whether or not I am going to play tennis (yes/no in binary).

For example, I have a table (and a dataframe of it) that has meteorological data sets. I construct the GLM model by seeing which one of these models the lowest p-value first

```
PlayTennis ~ Precip
PlayTennis ~ Temp, 
PlayTennis ~ Relative_Humidity
PlayTennis ~ WindSpeed)
```

Let's say `PlayTennis ~ Precip` has the lowest p-value.  So the next loop iteration in repeat is to see what other variable will have the lowest p-value.

```
PlayTennis ~ Precip + Temp
PlayTennis ~ Precip + Relative_Humidity 
PlayTennis ~ Precip + WindSpeed
```

This will continue until there are no more significant variables (P-value greater than 0.05). We thus get the final output of `PlayTennis ~ Precip + WindSpeed` (this is all hypothetical).

Is there any recommendation on how I can parallelize this code on various cores?  I have come across a new function for glm called `speedglm` from the library speedglm. This does improve but not by much.  I also looked into `foreach` loop but I am not sure on how it can communicate with each thread to know if which p-value is greater or lower for the various runs.  Thank you in advance for any help.

```
d =

Time          Precip    Temp    Relative_Humidity   WindSpeed   …   PlayTennis    
1/1/2000 0:00   0        88           30                0              1    
1/1/2000 1:00   0        80           30                1              1    
1/1/2000 2:00   0        70           44                0              1    
1/1/2000 3:00   0        75           49               10              0    
1/1/2000 4:00   0.78     64           99               15              0    
1/1/2000 5:00   0.01     66           97               15              0    
1/1/2000 6:00   0        74           88                8              0    
1/1/2000 7:00   0        77           82                1              1    
1/1/2000 8:00   0        78           70                1              1    
1/1/2000 9:00   0        79           71                1              1
```

The code that I have is as follows:

```
newNames <- names(d)
FRM <- "PlayTennis ~" 

repeat
{
    for (i in 1:length(newNames))
    {
        frm <- as.formula(paste(FRM, newNames[i], sep =""))
        GLM <- glm(formula = frm, na.action = na.exclude, # exclude NA values where they exist
                    data = d, family = binomial())
        # GLM <- speedglm(formula = frm, na.action = na.exclude, # exclude NA values where they exist
        #                 data = d, family = binomial())

        temp <- coef(summary(GLM))[,4][counter]

        if (i == 1) # assign min p value, location, and variable name to the first iteration
        {
            MIN <- temp
            LOC <- i
            VAR <- newNames[i]
        }

        if (temp < MIN) # adjust the min p value accordingly
        {
            MIN <- temp
            LOC <- i
            VAR <- newNames[i]
        }
    }

    if(MIN > 0.05) # break out of the repeat loop when the p-value > 0.05
    {
        break
    }

    FRM <- paste(FRM, VAR, " + ", sep = "") # create new formula
    newNames <- newNames[which(newNames != VAR)] # removes variable that is the most significant
    counter <- counter + 1
}
```

Code that I have tried but not working

```
newNames <- names(d)
FRM <- "PlayTennis ~" 

repeat
{
    foreach (i = 1:length(newNames)) %dopar%
    {
        frm <- as.formula(paste(FRM, newNames[i], sep =""))
        GLM <- glm(formula = frm, na.action = na.exclude, # exclude NA values where they exist
                    data = d, family = binomial())
        # GLM <- speedglm(formula = frm, na.action = na.exclude, # exclude NA values where they exist
        #                 data = d, family = binomial())

        temp <- coef(summary(GLM))[,4][counter]

        if (i == 1) # assign min p value, location, and variable name to the first iteration
        {
            MIN <- temp
            LOC <- i
            VAR <- newNames[i]
        }

        if (temp < MIN) # adjust the min p value accordingly
        {
            MIN <- temp
            LOC <- i
            VAR <- newNames[i]
        }
    }

    if(MIN > 0.05) # break out of the repeat loop when the p-value > 0.05
    {
        break
    }

    FRM <- paste(FRM, VAR, " + ", sep = "") # create new formula
    newNames <- newNames[which(newNames != VAR)] # removes variable that is the most significant
    counter <- counter + 1
}
```

Comment: `?step` or `?add1` will probably add speed gains before parallelising

Comment: Where does this data come from? Is it built in to a package?

Comment: If you're trying to do variable selection -- don't. Or rather, don't do it this way. Use a regularised approach, like elastic net. You can use the `glmnet` package for this.

Comment: or consider the `glmulti` package if you must.

Comment: @user20650, I have tried the step function, but it didn't lead to a model containing significant variables of interest.  Which is why I programmed my own "manual" yet automatic way of find the best model but it is quite time consuming and want to see if I can expand that over several cores if possible.

Comment: @Hack-R, the data is confidential, so I made up a random example to demonstrate my objective with a data set that looks like the real data.

Comment: @HongOoi, glmnet looks good but takes over an hour to run.  First time I hear about it, so I am learning as much as I can.  In addition, I am trying to see which variables glmnet believes to be the most significant, but doesn't seem to have that as an output.

Comment: @BenBolker, glmutli seems like a great package to use, however, my data set is quite large: 106596  x  137.  So when I try to run it, I came across a problem (oversized candidate).  Seems I still need to build my list manually to input it to glmulti.

Comment: If you don't specifically need to use pvalues then try stepAIC in the MASS package.

Comment: If the step routine doesn't keep any variables then you should reconsider your possible variables. But you could also use regsubsets to try every model combination and pick the best one.

Comment: @Dominik, unfortunately I will need to use p values.  I have tried stepAIC, initially, and it didn't provide a most accurate model needed in terms of significance.  Which is why I went to manually finding the optimal model.

I tried regsubsets, however, it takes a long time to find an optimal model.  Is there a way to parallelize it that you may know of?

Comment: I don't. Also, FYI, I'm fairly certain that of the parallel backends available, only with MPI can the slave processes talk to each other.

Comment: @Dominik Awesome!  Thank you for the suggestion.